# $1-\phi$ is surjective for a $\phi$-module?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

Let $A$ be a ring which is complete for the $p$-adic topology, in another word, there is an isomorphism between the two topological rings $A\rightarrow \lim_{\longleftarrow_{n \in \mathbb N_+}}  A/P^nA$. Assume $A/pA=k$ with $k$ is an algebraic closed field.(it is easy to see the characteristic of $k$ is $p$), so $A$ is endowed with a frobenius $\sigma$ lifting the map $x\rightarrow x^p$ in $k$.

Define $V$ is a free $A$ module of rank $n$ and with a map $\phi: V\rightarrow V$ which satisifies $\phi(k_1v_1+k_2v_2)=\sigma(k_1)\phi(v_1)+\sigma(k_2)\phi(v_2)$ and there exists a basis such that $Mat(\phi)\in GL_n(A)$.

Then the question is how to prove $1-\phi$ is surjective. This is an important fact metioned in [Laurent Berger's note](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/laurent.berger/autrestextes/CoursIHP2010.pdf) about $p$-adic Galois representations(page 19, after the proof of corollary 8.7).

Thanks!

Comment: The strategy here should be to reduce to the case of $k$- vector spaces via Nakayama's Lemma. That case, in turn, probably works via induction on dimension, the case of dimension $1$ relying on the existence of roots of $X^p-X-a$ by $k$ being algebraically closed (separable closure would suffice).